# Finding the probability function of $S$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

On two sides of a coin there are the numbers $-1,1$, trowing the coin $n$ times, les $S$ be the sum of the $n$ throwings, the probability to get $1$ is $p$,

> find the probability function of $S$

My try

$$-n\leq S\leq n$$

$$\Longrightarrow S\sim B(2n,p)$$

$$\Longrightarrow P_S(S=k)=\binom {2n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{2n-k}$$

> My attempt is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking with the binomial is a good idea. The details were not quite right.

Note that the possible values of $S$ range over all $k$ between $-n$ and $n$ that have the *same parity* as $n$.

Let $X$ be the number of $1$'s. Then $n-X$ is the number of $-1$'s, and $S=X-(n-X)=2X-n$. Thus 
$$\Pr(S=k)=\Pr(2X-n=k)=\Pr\left(X=\frac{n+k}{2}\right).$$ Now we can use the binomial distribution.